# ES2015 equivalent of $.Deferred()

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

I'm using Babel for a project, and I'm stuck with a very basic problem. I'm very used to jQuery's Deferred objects and I'm struggling to find its ES2015 equivalent, here is what I basically want:

```
// file1.js
let dfd = new Promise()

function functionCalledAtSomePoint(thing) {
    dfd.resolve(thing)
}

export default { dfd }


// file2.js
import { dfd } from './file1'

dfd.then((thing) => {
    console.log('Yay thing:', thing)
})
```

What should be the correct way to write this simple deferred?

**EDIT with royhowie's answer:**

```
// file1.js
let thing
function getThing(_thing) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        if (el) {
            thing = new Thing(el)
        }
        resolve(thing)
    })
}

function functionCalledAtSomePoint(el) {
    getThing(el)
}

export default { getThing }


// file2.js
import { getThing } from './file1'

getThing.then((thing) => {
    console.log('Yay thing:', thing)
})
```

Comment: babel has an informative "getting started" guide, which talks about promises in es6: https://babeljs.io/docs/learn-es2015/#promises

Comment: I read it first, then MDN, then things on Google and I still can't get my head around it :/

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I convert an existing callback API to promises?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22519784/1048572)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can export the promise directly (instead of a function)—like you have—but then you'll only be able to use it (`.then`) once, which is probably *not* what you want.

Instead, you should export a function which returns a `Promise`:

**file 1.js**

```
import User from '../models/user'

export function getUsersFromDatabase () {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        User.find({}, (err, users) => {
            return err ? reject(err) : resolve(users)
        })
    })
}
```

**file2.js**

```
import { getUsersFromDatabase } from './file1'

getUsersFromDatabase().then((users) => {
    // success
}).catch((err) => {
    // no users
})
```

You can use the default Promise implementation, [but it much slower than 3rd party modules](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/tree/master/benchmark), e.g., [bluebird](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird) (which I very much recommend using).

Comment: @JaromandaX then he can use the default implementation (which is currently very slow). bluebird is Promise/A+ standard compliant, so it should work as a drop-in replacement.

Comment: @zerkms I can't find the exact page I'm after, but https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/tree/master/benchmark is telling. Note how the native implementation is an order of magnitude slower (389 v. 3532).

Answer (score 5):

> I'm very used to jQuery's Deferred objects and I'm struggling to find its ES2015 equivalent

If you must use **deferred**, this should work

```
function makeDeferred() {
    var res, rej;
    let dfd = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        res = resolve;
        rej = reject;
    });
    dfd.resolve = res;
    dfd.reject = rej;
    return dfd;
}
let dfd = makeDeferred();
```

However, rewriting your code to avoid such kludge would be preferable (but not unavoidable - I still have **one** piece of code I can't get rid of the deferred promise in, so I feel your pain

Comment: that is the promise equivalent of jquery deffered - as I stated in my answer though, you should avoid the `deferred pattern`, but existing code can be a nightmare to convert at times

Comment: That's a good answer for somebody that might want to still use $.Deferred but it's not my case.

Comment: I misunderstood the question then :p

Answer (score 0):

This class will allow you to use the regular Promise methods as well as an additional `resolve(value)` method. This should give you a similar functionality as `jQuery.deferred()`.

```
function DeferredPromise() {
    var _resolve = null;
    var _reject = null;

    this.promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        _resolve = resolve;
        _reject = reject;
    });
    this.then = function() {
        return this.promise.then(...arguments);
    }
    this.catch = function() {
        return this.promise.catch(...arguments);
    }
    this.resolve = function() {
        _resolve(...arguments);
    }
    this.reject = function() {
        _reject(...arguments);
    }
}
```

Then you can use it to create a new *DeferredPromise*:

```
var p = new DeferredPromise();
```

Wait for it:

```
p.then(val => {
    console.log('val(1)', val);
})
```

Maybe wait for it another time, you can also chain it with a regular `Promise`:

```
p.then(val => {
    console.log('val(2)', val);
    return 42;
 }).then(val => {
    console.log('.then(somethingElse)', val);
 })
 .catch(err => { console.error('err', err); })
```

And resolve it whenever you want:

```
p.resolve({ username: 'Luke.Skywalker', age: 42 });
```